# why every image in my wordpress get large? even though the size of the image is small

Tags: wordpress, image, image-size

The size of the image is only 15x15. when i put in in wordpress. it automatically large. i want the default size. every image i put in wodpress is getting larger. even though I dont have any code to make it large.

[image]

here is my code:

```
<img src="http://mainvasdaq.compy.global/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Square_ble_Right-1.png" style="width"50%;" />
```

[image]

Comment: The code that you have mention above is quiet mistake it should be like this    style ="width:50%;" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a typo in your inline styling:

```
<img src="http://mainvasdaq.compy.global/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Square_ble_Right-1.png" style="width:50%;" />
```

General format of inline style is as follows:

```
style="attribute:value"
```

Be aware of the **:** between attribute and value in above syntax.

More info could be found in [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) or in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax)

Answer (score 0):

There is css written as

```
.dt-header-image img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

in your style.css line number 1846.

Please comment that or add below css

```
.dt-header-image button img {
    width: auto !important;
}
```